# How do I make ^ ^ ^ commands work from my perspective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Everytime I try to run a command with ^ ^ ^ format parameters, it always operates from the command block's perspective, even if I use `/execute`! Example command: 
`execute as pac2005_ run particle minecraft:end_rod ^ ^ ^1`

Update: Now that I've added a positioned as parameter, it follows me, but it doesn't follow the direction of my face, instead being a set direction from my feet.

Answer (score 1):

`as` changes who the command is running as (who `@s` refers to), but not where the command is running or the rotation of the command. You should instead use `at`:

```
execute at pac2005_ run particle minecraft:end_rod ^ ^ ^1
```